# Why, intuitively, are propositional resolution proofs so long?

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs, big-picture

I'm trying to gain an intuitive understanding of why propositional resolution proofs tend to be so long.

As every essential prime implicant can be produced via resolution, intuitively I would have guessed that lower bounds on the length of resolution would be left open, or perhaps even equivalent to whether NP = co-NP. However, it is proven that resolution proofs can have exponential lower bounds, as shown by Tseitin's and Haken's work on the pigeonhole principle.

This establishes resolution as being a lot less useful than one would hope, and indeed this is so well known that modern solvers look at all manner of other refutation proofs.

Trying a resolution proof on a pigeonhole principle formula quickly yields an explosion of mostly useless clauses with tons of literals, but I don't exactly understand *why* this is the case.

Is there some ultra-simple example that can illustrate where resolution goes wrong, or provide some intuition for why auxiliary variables can (at least sometimes) rectify this  issue?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65017/discussion-on-question-by-mike-battaglia-why-intuitively-are-propositional-res).